# Element data is not allowed here in Android Studio data binding

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to make a kind of tick-tac-toe android app (though with a 4x4 grid). I decided using buttons to depict each grid square and wanted to use data bindings to bind the text on the buttons to data from a String[][] array that would represent the grid internally. I tried doing something similar to what was presented here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html so I created this class:

```
public class ModelJoc extends BaseObservable{

private String[][] tabla_joc;

public ModelJoc() {
    for (String[] line : tabla_joc)
        for (String element : line)
            element = "";

    tabla_joc[0][0] = "M";
    tabla_joc[0][1] = "W";
}
```

And then added the data binding to the activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tgeorge.temajoc.MainActivity">
<data>
    <variable
        name="state"
        type="com.example.tgeorge.temajoc.ModelJoc"/>
</data>
```

And then tried to set the text of a button to a value from the array:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@={state.getBlockState()[0][0]}"/>
```

But it gives me these errors: "Element data is not allowed here" as well as "Attribute is missing the android: prefix". I can't tell what I'm doing wrong from the example in the tutorial so the question is where exactly should I be putting these?

Comment: What is in the getBlockState()?

Comment: Also, you don't want `"@={...}"` in your Button. Try `"@{...}"`

Comment: @GeorgeMount getBlockState() returns tabla_joc. Changing from `"@={"` to `"@{"` didn't seem to have any effect. Trying to bind it to a simple field instead of a method also didn't work. I think it might be something related to the `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` layout I'm using as in the tutorial i was trying to follow and most others it is just a simple `layout`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I see the problem now. You must outline your layout with a `<layout>` tag:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.example.tgeorge.temajoc.MainActivity">
    <data>
      <variable
          name="state"
          type="com.example.tgeorge.temajoc.ModelJoc"/>
    </data>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- ... -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@{state.getBlockState()[0][0]}"/>
```

If you don't do that, android data binding won't recognize it as a data bound layout file.

Comment: This has indeed solved the XML errors that I was getting but the actual data binding itself doesn't seem to work. The text of the button I've binded is still empty. I also tried programmatically setting the button's text using `binding.button1.setText("m");` but it still comes up as blank.

Comment: It is possible that you didn't use the data bound layout. For example, if you used `DataBindingUtil.inflate()` instead of `DataBindingUtil.setContent()`.

Comment: I used `ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Are you remembering to set the layout into the Activity? For example: `setContentView(binding.getRoot());` It is a common problem to leave the default `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in their `onCreate()` and forget to set it to the data bound content instead.

Comment: Indeed this seems to have solved the issue with the text set by `binding.button1.setText("m");` not working. The XML binding still came up as blank but I've managed to find out it was because I hadn't assigned `state` to an instance of `ModelJoc`. After using `binding.setState(new ModelJoc())` everything seems to be working fine. Thank you very much for the help, it has been rather insightful!